# Is it possible to call OnMessageRecieved more than once using a button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to delete a FCM token from my custom database, so i was thinking, can i call "Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenRecieved" after clicking a button? So i can get it and do a SQL query to delete the row with that specific token.

i have "nToken" as a global.I've added a button in unity and added SiFunction to it as an OnClick event.

```
public void SiFunction(){
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenRecieved;
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageRecieved;
    formData.AddField ("token", nToken);
    StartCoroutine(consulta.sendData(formData, callback));

}


public void OnTokenRecieved(object sender,Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token)
{                                                                                
    Debug.Log ("Recieved Registration Token: " + token.Token);
    nToken = token.Token;
}

public void OnMessageRecieved(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log ("Recieved a new message from: " + e.Message.From);

}
```

I expect the FCM token, but the actual output is undefined.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but I do think you may be confusing subscribing to an event with calling the event handler.  `thing.Event += EventHandler;` subscribes to the event.  You *can* subscribe more than once, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Sorry, im not a native english speaker but i'll do my best:

I'm implementing a functionality that allows me to send notifications to my Unity app (IOs and Android), I have a server-side code that select the FCM tokens stored in my database and push the notifications to those devices, I read that you need to store the token after a login and delete the token after a logout. my problem is that the "OntokenRecieved" is called once after you open the app and my plan is to call it again to get the token and send it to the database to delete it after an user logout but i cant get the token again.

Comment: Just for your information, you misspell "receive" as "recieve" in much of your code, which makes reading it a bit harder on the eyes (and may cause you future issues). It does not look like it's related to your issues, but the question may still be clearer if you fix it first. Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand .. why would you want to call `OnTokenRecieved` from a button click then? Since you already store the value of token in `Start` I guess you mean you want to get a new token? Or do you rather want to simply use the already received (and apparently stored in a `nToken` field) token in another method invoked by the button click?

Comment: You also know that the code `formData.AddField ("token", nToken);
    StartCoroutine(consulta.sendData(formData, callback));` is most likely executed before `nToken` is actually set to a value ...? You should move `Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenRecieved;
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageRecieved;` rather to e.g. `Start` or whenever Firebase is initialized and disable the button until a token was actually received

Comment: Exactly, i want to get the current token again so i can use it in a SQL DELETE query (DELETE FROM table_name WHERE device_token = ntoken). Im gonna modify the code and check if i recieve the token with the suggestion u made.